# How do you know that the differential of the square of a variable is dx^2?

Tags: calculus

I am a math enthusiast trying to study calculus on my own. While I was reading, I came across two explanations for why dx<sup>2</sup> is equal to 2x*dx.

In one of them, y is taken as x<sup>2</sup>. Then y + dy = (x + dx)<sup>2</sup>. On expanding, you get x<sup>2</sup> + 2xdx + dx<sup>2</sup>. Since dx<sup>2</sup> is a term of the second order of smallness, it is discarded. So you get dy, which is dx<sup>2</sup>, to be equal to 2xdx.

The second one is from the book "Calculus for the Practical Man" where the derivative of d(x + c)<sup>2</sup> is taken to be d(x<sup>2</sup>) + 2cdx. Here, c is a constant added to x. d(c<sup>2</sup>) is discarded because c is a constant term. Then z = mx is taken and squared to get z<sup>2</sup>=m<sup>2</sup>x<sup>2</sup>. Differentiating, it becomes d(z<sup>2</sup>) = m<sup>2</sup>d(x<sup>2</sup>). Dividing this result by dz = mdx and z = mx, it becomes 1/z * dz<sup>2</sup>/dz = 1/x * dx<sup>2</sup>/dx

This tells us that the derivative of the square of a variable divided by the variable itself (multiplied by the reciprocal) is the same for any two variables r and z. It is, therefore, the same for all variables and has a fixed, constant value, say a. Then d(x<sup>2</sup>) = axdx. Then d[(x+c)<sup>2</sup>] = a(x+c)*d(x+c). Equating this equation with d(x<sup>2</sup>) + 2cdx will give the value of a to be equal to 2, hence the derivative becomes 2xdx.

Since both of these explanations give the same result, I expect them to be similar. How are these similar?

Comment: Hint:- $d(x+c)^2\not={d(x)^2}$, and both follow chain rule.

Comment: [Here is a page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/) with 122 proofs of the Pythagorean Theorem. All give the same result. Are the proofs all similar to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since both of these explanations give the same result, I expect them to be similar. How are these similar?

They are not, but why would you expect them to be so?

There may often be many dissimilar paths to the same destination.

The first path is far more direct, but requires passing through disregarding the infinitesimal of an infinitesimal; $(\mathrm dx)^2$.

The "Calculus for the Practical Man" takes a longer route to avoid this action.  It might be a little harder to follow, but it gets there just the same.

Comment: Is there a more intuitive way to understand J.E. Thompson's method?